# take a list of numbers (1 element) and break it into chunks with python?

Tags: python

I would like to take a var containing numbers and create a list of 2 digit numbers.

For instance:

```
x = 123456
```

I want to create a list of 2 digit chunks

```
y = [12,34,56]
```

I can't seem to figure this one out.

Comment: which part? split by two or convert to numbers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

Comment: You are not taking a list of numbers, `x` is just a number.

Comment: How do you want to handle the case of `x = 120034`?  The only way to have `00` is to use a string.

Comment: Also, how do you want to handle `x = 12345`? Or `x = 0`? Or `x = -123456`?

Comment: `n = 2; s = str(x); result = map(int, (s[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(s), n)))`

Answer (score 3):

Use modulo and floor division.

```
def chunks(n):
    if n < 0: raise Exception ("Don't")
    while n:
        yield n % 100
        n //= 100

a = [c for c in chunks (123456)][::-1]
print(a)
```

Also PS: For input `12345` the output is `[1, 23, 45]`.

And PPS: Is this for FFT multiplication?

Comment: Probably should add an explanatory note that `chunks` yields in reverse order, necessitating the reversing slice (`[::-1]`).  Also, it might be clearer to do `reversed([c for c in chunks (123456)])`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Very correct. The main point was to avoid costly string operations. The only possible application of splitting a number into its coefficients of a given base I see is FFT, and then hopefully the order doesn't matter as long as you stick to one and the same.

Comment: Thanks, this works for a string but how bout an int?

Comment: @user2270470 This doesn't work for a string... It takes an `int` (in my example `123456`).

Answer (score 0):

If `x` is string:

```
x = '1234563'

a = [x[i * 2 : (i + 1) * 2] for i in range(len(x) // 2)]
```

If `x` is int:

```
x = 1234563

l = len(str(x))
a = [(x // (10 ** (i - 2))) % 100 for i in range(l, 2, -2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> x = 123456
>>> [int(str(x)[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len((str(x)), 2)]
[12, 34, 56]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def trunk(numbers, chunkSize):
    new_list = []
    nums = str(numbers)
    for x in xrange(0, len(nums), chunkSize):
        new_list.append(int(nums[x:chunkSize+x]))
    return new_list

>>> x = 123456
>>> trunk(x, 2)
[12, 34, 56]
>>> x = 12345
>>> trunk(x, 2)
[12, 34, 5]
```